# How to prove gradient with exponent

Tags: real-analysis

To be honest I'm stucking as far as proofs are concerned so I hope you were to push me a little.

I got to show:

$\quad f(h x) = h^k  f(x)  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \nabla f(x) \cdot x = k  f(x)$

(Given: $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n,\quad k\in\mathbb{R},\quad h\in\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Recall that the gradient is defined as $\nabla f(x) = (Df)(x)^{T}$ at some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The $(Df)(x)$ matrix is the jacobian matrix. Now, the rest ...

Comment: yea, I know $\nabla f(x) = (\partial_1 f(x),...,\partial_n f(x))$ So I have to figure out what $\partial_1 f(x) $ ist exactly. I think the clue is to derive with respect to h hence $\partial_h f(h \cdot x) = \partial_h h^k \cdot f(x)$. But there's where I lose track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

For each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ consider the function $\phi_x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\phi_x(h)=h\,x$$

Define $F(h)=f\circ\phi_x (h)=f(h\,x)$

Use the chain rule:

$$F'(h)=f'(\phi_x(h))\phi'_x(h)$$

On the one hand,
$$F'(h)=\nabla f(hx) \cdot x=\nabla f(hx)\cdot x$$
On the other hand,

$F(h)=h^k f(x)$ and so
$$F'(h)=k h^{k-1} f(x)$$

Consequently

$$ \nabla f(hx)\cdot x = k h^{k-1} f(x)$$

In particular, for $h=1$ we get

$$ \nabla f(x)\cdot x = k f(x)$$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Apologize my rude inquiry, I was used to ask for a solutions and receive it straight away. But I acknowledge your method of teasing me is deductively more beneficial. So here's what I got: Let $g(x) = h \cdot x$ and $F(x) = f(x) \circ g(x)$. Thus: $\partial_h F(x) = \partial_h f(x\cdot h) \cdot x$ and per Definition it's equal to: $\partial_h h^k \cdot f(x) = k \cdot h^{k-1} \cdot f(x)$. That's almost the solution but I wonder why $h$ has to be $1$ to fulfill the condition?